# Is there a C# library that can render LaTeX and TikZ? (If not, directions for writing one)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am looking for a library that can can be used with Xamarin Forms to render LaTeX and TikZ. [CSharpMath](https://github.com/verybadcat/CSharpMath) renders LaTeX perfectly, but does not support TikZ.

If there is no such library, I would like some pointers to start developing my own solution. In my mind it would be as simple as:

1. Parse the TikZ (Using ANTLR?)
2. Draw using SkiaSharp

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What shall be the output? Screen? PNG? svg? I think, a good idea would be to contact the author of tikz. In Inkscape, there is a tikz output, if I remember correctly, that might help you also.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such c# libraries to render TikZ. If they were available, I would have not written my solutions with SkiaSharp [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A87876+skiasharp).

Comment: Can you involve TeX at all?  Using TeX to parse the input would make it much easier, then you would just need to write an appropriate backend.

Comment: @AndrewStacey I can involve TeX to some degree. Can you clarify what you mean by using TeX to parse the input? As far as I know, DVI files would also be difficult to parse, but I'd like to hear your thoughts.

Comment: TikZ, using TeX, processes its input and simplifies it considerably before sending it to a backend to render it to the desired format.  It would be easier to intercept it at that point rather than at the outset.